# pragram giving error when character pointer is assigned null value?

Tags: c++

I have following two versions of code

correctly working program

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{

const char *q="+\0";
char *p=""; //working correct with ""
strncpy(p,q,2);
cout<<p;
}
```

Program giving error

```
 #include<iostream.h>
 #include<string.h>

void main()
{

const char *q="+\0";
char *p=NULL; //Program gives error abnormal termination when *p=NULL or *p="\0"
strncpy(p,q,2);
cout<<p;
}
```

I am not understanding the two different behavior of the   `char *p` in these code samples.
Please help.

Comment: you are trying to modify `string literal` which invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

No part of your program is correct. The memory that contains string literals *must not be modified*, so you must never copy to the location `p`.

You must only access memory that you personally obtained for your own use, like so:

```
char p[500];
strncpy(p, "+\0", 2);    // OK, *p is yours
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you actually mean when `p == NULL` (from your comment)

`*p == NULL` just means `p` points to some address which holds the value `0`.

In other words `*p == NULL` and `p == NULL` are two completely different things.

So if you tried to edit the memory where `p` points to, and that memory is address `0x0000` (also known as `NULL`) that is pretty much guaranteed to fail, because you likely do not own this memory.

When I say own, I mean your program has allocated memory at this location. If you write `char *p = new char;` then your program allocates some `sizeof(char)` bytes of memory. And now if you modify the value of `*p` that is okay because you have been **given** the memory (by the operating system or whatever).